# How to add multiply animation to the view in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I want to add multiple animations to the view. I just can add one,...  I do not want to concatenate

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:kAnimationDuration];
//self.square.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.square.bounds.size.height, 200);
//self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 1);


CGAffineTransform scaleTrans1 = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 1);

self.transform = scaleTrans1;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Could you be clearer about exactly what you want the animation to do? are you trying to trigger an animation after another? or do more than one thing at the same time?

Comment: I want to add scale trasform for the view and once it is finished another scale transform. one after one...
ex:  (current size) --> (2,1) --> (current size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did like this and its working

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:4.0f animations:^{
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 1);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:4.0f animations:^{
           self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 1);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){
            [UIView animateWithDuration:4.0f animations:^{
              self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 1);  
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                [UIView animateWithDuration:4.0f animations:^{
                    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 1);
                }];
            }];
        }];
    }];


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use animateWithDuration (in any of its variations) from UIView, as long as the properties you are trying to animate are actually animatable (view [UIView / Animations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW131)).

For example:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
animations: ^ {
    self.square.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.square.bounds.size.height, 200);
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 1);
}];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: still I can not add multiple transformation to the view.. I tried this, but only the second one is executed